# Gunicorn not reloading code completely with the HUP signal

Tags: gunicorn, django-deployment

I'm running gunicorn and I use the HUP signal to reload gunicorn gracefully. However, it seems that changes in models.py are not reloaded for some reason. To be specific I do:

`` sudo kill -HUP `cat masterpid` ``

I also run gunicorn with supervisor, so I end up doing a hard restart of gunicorn with supervisor, but it is not graceful and there is a second or two of downtime (plus some possibly broken requests). Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem. django.db.connections is not updated for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using run_gunicorn (now deprecated)?

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/536

Comment: We actually ended up abandoning the `run_gunicorn` command recently when we upgraded to django 1.6 as it was giving us a TransactionManagementError very frequently. As a side note, I've now realized we haven't had this issue any longer!